# What preposition do I use after the word "consideration"?

Tags: prepositions

What preposition do I use after the word "consideration" in the following case?

This is the sentence:

> ...... which brought me to the consideration _______ applying for this job.

Comment: It's unidiomatic to use 'consideration' here.  '... which led me to consider applying for this job'.

Comment: Before or after?  Your title says "before", the question body says "after".

Comment: (And the sentence is poorly worded from the git-go.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth exactly what I was about to say. Casper, is this part of a covering letter?